# Check if pixels lie within ellipse area in Python

Tags: python, polygon, ellipse

I'm trying to create true/false mask based on test whether pixels are inside ellipse area or not.

Straightforward ways were proposed here - [Counting points inside an ellipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187996/counting-points-inside-an-ellipse)

However, I'm wondering if there's more elegant solution to this, like [matplotlib.nxutils](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/nxutils_api.html). If I want to use nxutils then I have to convert my ellipse to polygon somehow, which creates more complications and introduces additional error to calculations.

Is there any module capable of running this kind of check with ellipses?

Comment: some quick googeling gives [this](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/540650-checking-a-point-inside-a-ellipse/), perhaps helpful...

Comment: How the ellipse is represented, as set of boundary pixels or as a equation?

Comment: @nutario: The ellipse is represented by equation.