# Calculating average pixel RGB values in an ellipse

Tags: python, matplotlib, ellipse

I have a B&W image of galaxy and I need to measure the average pixel RGB values for each concentric ellipse like so:

[image]

The code so far is

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot, lines
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imread
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse
dpi=80
im_data = imread('test.png')
height, width, nbands = im_data.shape
print height, width
figsize = width / float(dpi), height / float(dpi)
print figsize
fig = plt.figure(figsize=figsize)
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.axis('off')
ax.imshow(im_data, interpolation='nearest')
for i in range(10,400,10):
    ell = Ellipse(xy=[240,268], width=i, height=i*0.9, angle=70, edgecolor='b',lw=4, alpha=0.3,facecolor='none')
    ax.add_artist(ell)

plt.show()
```

So my questions are:

1)Is there an easy way to extract the coordinates of each point (to a logical degree of uncertainty, at least 20 points-ish)?

2)The next step seems easier since we can use the `pix=im.load()` and pix[x,y] to get the RGB values. Am I wrong in this assumtion?

Comment: What's a "B&W" image if it has RGB values?

Comment: see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8187996/counting-points-inside-an-ellipse?rq=1: some ways of calculating the ellipse are much more efficient than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, this is definitely possible. If you know where your coordinate system starts and ends and the pixel scale (in each axis), then you can construct a couple of coordinate matrices, sort of like this:

```
x = np.linspace(xll, xul, im.shape[1])
y = np.linspace(yll, yul, im.shape[0])
XX, YY = np.meshgrid(x, y)
```

[`np.meshgrid()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is one of my workhorse functions as an optical astronomer--definitely familiarize yourself with it.

Now let's say your the world-coordinate (not to be confused with your pixel coordinate) of your central pixel is `ctr`. You can calculate each pixel's distance from that center using the formula `d = np.sqrt((ctr[0] - XX)**2 + (ctr[1] - YY)**2.)` This is the Euclidean distance metric, and uses the Pythagorean theorem. (You can also use broadcasting rules and `sum()` with an `axis` argument to make this a little more compact, but for beginners, the syntax I used is a little more readable.)

If you want to make ellipses with an axis ratio unequal to 1, then just multiply one of the terms in the distance metric formula above by a constant. Use [`plt.contour()`](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/contour_demo.html) on the resulting matrix to get a feel for how that scales. You can also get rotated ellipses by multiplying `XX` and `YY` by a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) (making sure that your subtract off `ctr` before applying the transformation--otherwise you'll get wild results).

I haven't used `imread` much, but it looks like it yields an M x N x 3 array. So to figure out the average R value of all pixels within a distance `r` from `ctr`, you calculate `np.mean(im[:, :, 0][d < r])`